# Как реализовать отображение рук от первого лица, подобное в CS:GO, Overwatch , используя Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Я не нашел примеров и туториалов для реализации отображения рук от первого лица (возможно, я плохо искал). Можете подсказать, как это реализовать?

[пример CS:GO](https://cs12.pikabu.ru/post_img/2019/08/28/4/1566971510110195432.webm)

[пример Overwatch](https://thumbs.gfycat.com/AnimatedDelayedBaleenwhale-size_restricted.gif)

Comment: Я конечно не гейм-дев, но могу предположить, что это достигается путём изменения положения камеры

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Туториал:

- нарисовать руки и сделать все необходимые анимации рук
- Создать капсуль который будет отвечать за игрока
- Повесить на капсуль скрипт контроллера для того что бы можно было управлять персонажем
- Повесить руки на капсуль и сделать их видимыми только для этой камеры, для иных камер отображать модель полноценного человека (которого так же следует нарисовать и проанимировать)
- отредактировать положение рук, положение камеры и т.д. что бы все работало

это общая теория того что необходимо сделать.